# Manupulate inline defined color with CSS or SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

Is there a way to detect a color what was defined in html and then manipulate it? (ex saturate?) 
I tried using inherit, but it doesn't seem to work

```
<div class="parent" style="background-color: #0F546D">
<span class="child></span>
</div>

.child {
background-color: saturate(inherit, 50%)
}
```

Comment: the only way you can override inline style is using `!important` flag.

Comment: I don't think you can use `inherit` like that.

Comment: You can use black/white background-color on child, and then use opacity. Just an ugly fix :<

Comment: How do you think this is even supposed to work?  Sass is a compiled language and is never sent to the client.  How do you think it is going to know what is in your markup?